# Upload multiple images to FTP server in iOS

Tags: swift, ftp, swift4, xcode9, image-upload

I'm developing an application in swift 4. In it, I want to upload multiple images to FTP server. I have tried to do with https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka but could not build getting error saying 
Xcode 9 does not support building or migrating Swift 2.x targets.

Also tried with https://gist.github.com/Nirma/fb9991be776107d17fdcd6ed2aa02876 . But some of the APIs are deprecated. Apple sample project is in objective C. Can anybody please help me to go forward in this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For starters, please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Coming back to your problem, it explicitly states on the library's Github page that it requires Swift 2.0. You cannot build Swift 2.0 code with Swift 4.0 without migration.

Comment: @Malik :  Thank you for sharing the links regarding "How to ask question". Will follow from next time onwards. And regarding the image uploading, is there a preference(in programing or security) for uploading to http server over ftp server. Is it because there is limited support for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented FilesProvider library to abstract FTP/FTPS, WebDAV, Dropbox and OneDrive and providing a high level, `FileManager` like API to deal with these.

You can use [FilesProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider) library to deal with FTP. It doesn't use deprecated `CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL` API and implements FTP protocol from scratch.

Please read Readme before using. You can see a sample implementation for iOS [here](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider/blob/master/Docs/Sample-iOS.swift).

Comment: Thank you. I will try with this

Comment: hey  Mousavian I'm facing an issue while uploading a file to ftp can you please help, i posted the issue on github